# Increment MAC address

Tags: perl

I'm trying to develop a script which will, in part, generate a list of MAC addresses from a given starting base.  What I have as input is a list of MAC addresses, and need to increment by 1.

Examples:

`00:1D:FE:12:37:1A` (need to generate `00:1D:FE:12:37:1B`)
`00:1D:FE:12:37:49` (need to generate `00:1D:FE:12:37:4A`)
`00:1D:FE:12:37:4F` (need to generate `00:1D:FE:12:37:50`)

The restriction here is that I need to run this script on a machine that has no "extra" perl modules neither installed nor available, so the code would need to be included within the script.  This means `Net::MAC` is out as a module, but I could potentially cannibalize some useful bits and include it but I'm thinking what I'm trying to do shouldn't be entirely complex to implement in a small function utilizing pack(?) or something of the like.

I've found various threads around on forums like PerlMonks, but no one seems to have a conclusive answer.  Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a 48-bit number. Parse it, increment it, format it.

Many Perl builds only support 32-bit numbers as integers, so I'll avoid forming larger ints.

```
my $mac_str = '00:1D:FE:12:37:1A';

( my $mac_hex = $mac_str ) =~ s/://g;
my ($mac_hi, $mac_lo) = unpack("nN", pack('H*', $mac_hex));

if ($mac_lo == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
    $mac_hi = ($mac_hi + 1) & 0xFFFF;
    $mac_lo = 0;
} else {
    ++$mac_lo;
}

$mac_hex = sprintf("%04X%08X", $mac_hi, $mac_lo);
$mac_str = join(':', $mac_hex =~ /../sg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know perl but I have done macaddress increment in python. The code is added here

```
def getmacaddress_increment(macinst, rowindex):
inst = gethex_todecimal(macinst)
macarray = inst.split('.')
instarr = []
seg5 = int(macarray[5]) + rowindex       
if seg5 > 255:
    macarray[5] = str(seg5%255)
    seg4 = int(macarray[4])
    macarray[4] = str(seg4 + int(seg5/255))
else:
    macarray[5] = str(seg5)

seg4 = int(macarray[4])           
if seg4 > 255:
    macarray[4] = str(seg4%255)
    seg3 = int(macarray[3])
    macarray[3] = str(seg3 + int(seg4/255))
else:
    macarray[4] = str(seg4)

seg3 = int(macarray[3])           
if seg3 > 255:
    macarray[3] = str(seg3%255)
    seg2 = int(macarray[2])
    macarray[2] = str(seg2 + int(seg3/255))
else:
    macarray[3] = str(seg3)

seg2 = int(macarray[2])
if seg2 > 255:
    macarray[2] = str(seg2%255)
    seg1 = int(macarray[1])
    macarray[1] = str(seg1 + int(seg2/255))

seg1 = int(macarray[1])
if seg1 > 255:
    macarray[1] = '0'
    seg0 = int(macarray[0])
    macarray[0] = str(seg0 + 1)

seg0 = int(macarray[0])
if seg0 > 255:
    macarray[0] = '0'
arr = []
#newval = macarray[0] + '.' + macarray[1] + '.' + macarray[2] + '.' + macarray[3] + '.' + macarray[4] + '.' + macarray[5]        
#print 'Updated value: ', newval
for cnt, instr in enumerate(macarray):
   arr.append("%0.2x" % int(instr))
return ':'.join(arr)

def toint(macid):   
    return str(int(macid, 16))

def gethex_todecimal(macaddr):
   macaddr = macaddr.replace('-', ':')
   inst = map(toint, macaddr.split(':'))
   return '.'.join(inst)
```

Check if you could use this logic to increment in perl. Sorry i dont have a straight forward answer.

Siva

Comment: Actually, I'm a fairly interested Python newbie as well, so this is a cool reference to have!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using code for increment the MAC ADDRESS of but at last position,when we increment the MAC ADDRESS it overflow SO, I used code start from 00

for example: if last position is FF it to starting point 00

```
#!/bin/sh
mac=$(ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr|awk '{print $5}'| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | cut -d ':' -f1-5)
maclast=$(ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr|awk '{print $5}'| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | cut -d ':' -f6)
echo "Mac address= $mac:$maclast"
decmac=$(echo "ibase=16; $maclast"|bc)
echo $decmac
if [ $decmac -eq '241' ]
then
    macinc='00'
else
    incout=`expr $decmac + 1 `
    macinc=$(echo "obase=16; $incout"|bc)
fi
echo "Mac address= $mac:$macinc"
```

OUTPUT:

Mac address= 00:19:D1:F6:F7:FF

Mac address= 00:19:D1:F6:F7:00

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing the MAC ADDRESS by 1:

```
#!/bin/sh

mac=$(ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr|awk '{print $5}'| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | cut -d ':' -f1-5)

maclast=$(ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr|awk '{print $5}'| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | cut -d ':' -f6)

echo "Mac address= $mac:$maclast" 

hexmac=$(echo "ibase=16; $maclast"|bc)

incout=`expr $hexmac + 1 `

macinc=$(echo "obase=16; $incout"|bc)

echo "Mac address= $mac:$macinc"
```

OUTPUT:

```
Mac address= 00:19:D1:F6:F7:F1
Mac address= 00:19:D1:F6:F7:F2
```

Answer (score -1):

Download Net::Mac and shove it into your script as a module

```
/tydel.pl
         /Net
             /Mac.pl
```

Comment: @tydel: so you *package up the cpan module in your tarball*. :)

Comment: there's an endless stream of people who claim that they're not allowed to use code from CPAN, but they are allowed to use code from PerlMonks, StackOverflow, etc. Yeah, it doesn't make much sense. In frustration, I've copied modules from CPAN to PerlMonks before, hehe.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby:

`def gen_next_mac(base_mac, rowindex)
        mac_ints = base_mac.split(':').map {|s| s.to_i(16).to_s(10).to_i}
        mac_ints[5] += rowindex
        if mac_ints[5] > 255
            mac_ints[5] = mac_ints[5]%255
            mac_ints[4] = mac_ints[4] + mac_ints[5]/255
        end
        if mac_ints[4] > 255
            mac_ints[4] = mac_ints[4]%255
            mac_ints[3] = mac_ints[3] + mac_ints[4]/255
        end
        if mac_ints[3] > 255
            mac_ints[3] = mac_ints[3]%255
            mac_ints[2] = mac_ints[2] + mac_ints[3]/255
        end
        if mac_ints[2] > 255
            mac_ints[2] = mac_ints[2]%255
            mac_ints[1] = mac_ints[1] + mac_ints[2]/255
        end
        if mac_ints[1] > 255
            mac_ints[1] = mac_ints[1]%255
            mac_ints[0] = mac_ints[0] + mac_ints[1]/255
        end
        return mac_ints.map {|i| '%02x' %i }.join(':')
    end`

Comment: Since the question is tagged `perl` and your answer is in `ruby`, perhaps some explanation to go along with the code would help.

Comment: Has this algorithm been adequately tested? I was trying it out, and I see it doesn't increment properly after 255 (if base value for mac_ints[5] is 00, at rowindex 256 it becomes 01 instead of 00, also it doesn't roll over mac_int[4]). A partial fix is to store the current mac_int[n] to a temp variable then use the temp variable in the division and modulo to get the correct values for the next mac_int[n+1] and also to subtract 1 after the modulo to account for case of rollover to 00 instead of 01 from 0xFF for the current N in mac_int[N].

Comment: An alternate and perhaps more accurate implementation for Ruby 1.9+ would be to replace the code implementation of the function/method with this: `return ("0x#{base_mac.gsub(/:/,'')}".hex + rowindex).to_s(16).gsub(/(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})/,'\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6')` but I did notice for this, you have to zero pad the left most pair of digits before calling gsub if the MAC address ends up starting with "00:xx", otherwise it's ok.